# Why is an array argument treated as a const array?

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments, constants

I am working with a member function that just sets the object's internal orientation to the values given in the argument:

```
void A::SetOrientation(float a[3]);
```

In another class, I have the following:

```
class B
{
public:
  RestoreStateTo(A* const o_pA) const
private:
  float d_orientation[3];
};

void 
B::RestoreStateTo(A* const o_pA) const
{
   o_pA->SetOrientation(d_orientation);
}
```

I get the following compiler error (with Visual Studio 2010):

```
error C2664: 'void A::SetOrientation(float [])' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const float [3]' to 'float []'
```

I found that I can avoid the issue with `o_pA->SetOrientation(const_cast<float *>(d_orientation));`, but I'd like to get a better grasp of what is going on.

I would appreciate an explanation as to why the array argument is converted to a `const` array as well as suggest the right approach to dealing with the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the prototype of your function void B::RestoreStateTo(A* const o_pA) const says you will not modify any member of B.
Since d_orientation is an attribute of B, it is const in this function.

Comment: +1; the right approach to dealing with the error is to add `const` to `A::SetOrientation`'s `a` parameter if it is in fact not going to modify it.

Comment: Of course.  Thanks.  `SetOrientation` in my case is in a third party library, but will not modify the input.  So in this case is `const_cast` the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Your SetOrientation function should take in a const,

```
void A::SetOrientation(const float a[3]);
```

Otherwise, it's possible that A::SetOrientation will modify the array you pass in. Because you have "B::RestoreStateTo(A* const o_pA) **const**", it means that the compiler won't let you pass a pointer to B::d_orientation as a non-const input, because A::SetOrientation has no guarantee not to modify it.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared a `const` member function, and therefore all the members of `this` will be treated as `const` inside that function.  So it shouldn't be surprising that `d_orientation` is treated as `const`.

It's the same principle that makes this code illegal:

```
const B* p = ...;
p->d_orientation[0] = 0.0f; // error, assigning member of `const` object
```

Comment: Nonsense, A::SetOrientation is not a *const* member function.

Comment: @Hans: `B::RestoreStateTo` is a `const` member function.  Take time to actually *read the question* before posting inane comments, please.